# Mysql query to only return rows based on column of first row

Tags: mysql

Sorry for the title, hard to explain in one line, but I am after a query that can get me all the rows based on the result of the first row - an example will explain:

Table looks like this

```
id | name | week
1     x      2
2     y      2
3     z      3
```

So basically without knowing the first `week` value, I want only those rows where `week = 2`.  In other words, if the next run, the first result is `week: 3`, then I only want rows where `week = 3`.

This is all contingent on the correct ordering of the rows - but that is not the purpose of this.

I've thought about doing it in two queries given this be inside some php app, where the first query

```
select week from table limit 1
```

And therefore, now we know the `week` value, can simply

```
select id, name, week from table where week = '2'
```

But I figured there was a smarter way to do it in one query, just not sure what that sql function might look like.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: for get different week in each (next)  run  you should iterate (with a loop)  over the result of all distinct week  .. otherwise you obtain always the same result  ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding from your steps and thinking, you could do

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE week = (SELECT week FROM table LIMIT 1)`

The above should work fine (unless I misunderstood the question).

Comment: thankyou - I think I was just looking for some fancy sql function when the simple solution does the trick :)